# Split and Crop a string array in Java

Tags: java

I have a little problem with a String.
The String looks like this one:

`A/46\-54.67/48\-6.94/52\2.41/54\0.00/38\-0.18/34\0.06/32\-27.22 (...)`

It's an answer from a UDP-Request.
The Request was like: R/46/48(...)/32(...) , it means: give me the value for #46,#48 ...
The answer is shown above.

**Aim:**

Finally I only want the specific values as a double from the String for each request.

My favorite would be a class with 3(or 2) args.
The first argument will be the String it self, the second would be the position inside the String (like Value after 46\ ). And, if needed , a third for the end of the Value, like /. It returns a array with the values.

(Not a real Solution for me: I can only request on Value at once, so the answer will be easier to work with. Problem, if have to do much more UDP Requests per Time. Current the Request will be 10 Times a Second, ultimatley it will be much more often. And i have to calculate with the values)

**Problem:**

The String is not consistent.
The returned Values can have different digits and can be signed or not.
Consistent is only: `A/46\(digit for value 46)/48\(digit)/52\(digit)/54\(digit)/38\_/34\_/32\_`
As you can see, the Value is between "\ /".
I got a "solution" that cuts the Values a specific positions. But it failed when the digits changed.

**Solution?**

(Yes, I'm a real Java Greenhorn)
My tries gave me a array that looks like this one:

A/46

-54.67/48

-6.94/52

2.41/54

0.00/38

-0.18/34

0.06/32

-27.22

So, and now i don't have a clue how to get the last part off the Value to convert them it into a double(array).

I hope I've described my Problem vividly.

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: How are you trying to parse it? You should use the StringTokenizer class to split it on the / . Then each - token after some validation - you can split again on the \.

Answer (score 3):

Start by splitting with `/`; you will get a string array looking like:

```
[ "A", "46\\-54.67", ... ]
```

Forget the first element; then, for each other element, do:

```
Double.parseDouble(theElement.subString(theElement.indexOf('\\')))
```

This will get you the `double` you want; all you have left to do is get these `double`s where you want them.

Another solution is to cycle through the string with this regex:

```
(\d+)\\(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

The first group of the regex captures the integer, the second captures the double:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\\\(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)");

final Matcher m = p.matcher(resultString);

while (m.find())
     // deal with m.group(1), m.group(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This regex based code might work for you:

```
String str = "A/46\\-54.67/48\\-6.94/52\\2.41/54\\0.00/38\\-0.18/34\0.06/32\\-27.22/38";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)/(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Before: %s, After: %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Before: -54.67, After: 48
Before: -6.94, After: 52
Before: 2.41, After: 54
Before: 0.00, After: 38
Before: -0.18, After: 34
Before: -27.22, After: 38
```

#### EDIT: To put these matched values in ArrayLists:

```
String str = "A/46\\-54.67/48\\-6.94/52\\2.41/54\\0.00/38\\-0.18/34\0.06/32\\-27.22/38";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)/(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<Double> beforeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Integer> afterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (m.find()) {
    beforeList.add(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)));
    afterList.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
}
System.out.printf("Before: %s, After: %s%n", beforeList, afterList);
```

Comment: I would `static final` the compiled pattern so it doesn't have to be recompiled each time the str is parsed, but I think this approach would perform a little better than multiple String.split[] calls.  However, this solution is wrong though in my understanding - the wrong code is matched up to the wrong value.  Changing the pattern to something like `[A]?/(\\d+)\\\\([\\-]?\\d+\\.\\d+)` would line up the codes and values.

Comment: @n0741337: No solution isn't wrong, you can try above code yourself. And yes I agree that compiled pattern can be made static final for better performance.

Comment: I think that the "46" group should line up with "-54.67" group in that the value returned for code "46" follows it in the str.  I did compare the outputs of both.  I think there should be 7 find()s, not 6.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution of fge. I gave it a shot and tried it. It works great. But my problem with this one are the groups. I tried to write the values into an array, but this wasn`t that easy.
So i tried the solution of Ruchira and this one gives me what i need.
But i will have a closer look at this solution.
Thanks to all for the super fast responses.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you some coding help in populating array lists with the matched values.

Answer (score 1):

I typed this in without using the IDE so there may be some minor mistakes:

```
//Split at /
String[] parts = udpResponse.split("/");

//for each part (apart from the initial A)
for (int i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {

   //the part is of the form aaa\bbb where aaa and bbb are numbers
   String[] keyValue = parts[i].split("\\");
   double key = Double.parseDouble(keyValue[0]); //number before \
   double value = Double.parseDouble(keyValue[1]); //number after \

   //do whatever you like with the numbers... 
}
```

Comment: +1 Using String.split() is enough for this question. Regexes from the other answers are more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   String test="A/46\\-54.67/48\\-6.94/52\\2.41/54\\0.00/38\\-0.18/34\\0.06/32\\-27.22";
   String[] arr=test.split("\\\\");
   double[] dub=new double[arr.length];
   int k=0;
   for (String i:arr){
        if(i.split("/").length!=1) {
        dub[k]=Double.parseDouble(i.split("/")[1].trim());
        k++;
        }
   }
```

Comment: This works, almost. It gives me an array, but unfortunately with the keys and not the values. So i turned the \\\\ and / around. And it worked. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). This is a handy function for relatively simple string parsing such as your example here. First you need to split the UDP reply on the '/'. It looks like you ignore the first and last `String`s in the resulting array. For the remaining `String`s, you can use a for loop to call `String.split()` on each of them in turn, splitting on the '\' character.